# How to iterate over list(string) and append to same records Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, txt

I want to iterate over list of string and apply individual vale to same resource route53
I have list of ip in variable

```
variable "app_list" {
description = "List of ESAs to be allowed. (For instance, \[192.168.1.123, 10.1.1.11\] etc.)"
type        = list(string)
default = \["192.168.1.123","10.1.1.11"\]
}
```

Creating route53 TXT record where I have to append this variable and create single record

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "spf_txt" {
zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
name = ""
type = "TXT"
ttl = 300

records = \["v=spf1 ip4:192.168.1.123 ip4:10.1.1.11 \~all"\]
}
```

Here i used for_each and count. it is trying to create two seperate TXT record. How can I iterate the list and pass it to record.

Please someone help me

Tried :

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "spf_txt" {
zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
name = ""
type = "TXT"
ttl = 300
count = length(var.app_list)
for_each = var.app_list
records = \["v=spf1 ip4:value \~all"\]
}
```

It errored as two elements with tuples

tried this as well

```
locals {
spf_record = "${formatlist("ip4:", var.app_list)}" 
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "spf_txt" {
zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
name = "" 
type = "TXT"
ttl = 300
records = \["v=spf1 ${local.spf_record} ip4:${data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_ip.public_ip} \~all"\]
}
```

It failed with this error
spf_record = "${formatlist("ip4:", var.app_list)}"
while calling formatlist(format, args...)
var.app_esas is list of string with 2 elements

Call to function "formatlist" failed: error on format
iteration 0: too many arguments; no verbs in format
string.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't use `count` or `for_each` you would accomplish the purpose, I think.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "spf_txt" {
  ...
  records = ["v=spf1 ${join(" ", [for i in var.app_list : "ip4:${i}"])} ~all"]
}
```

Test:

```
variable "app_list" {
  description = "List of ESAs to be allowed. (For instance, [192.168.1.123, 10.1.1.11] etc.)"
  type        = list(string)
  default = ["192.168.1.123","10.1.1.11"]
}

output "spf_txt" {
  value = ["v=spf1 ${join(" ", [for i in var.app_list : "ip4:${i}"])} ~all"]
}
```

```
$ terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + spf_txt = [
      + "v=spf1 ip4:192.168.1.123 ip4:10.1.1.11 ~all",
    ]
```

If using `formatlist`:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "spf_txt" {
  ...
  records = ["v=spf1 ${join(" ", formatlist("ip4:%s", var.app_list))} ~all"]
}
```